# How to design usage of Global temp table for a multi-user environment? (or alternatives)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, temp-tables

I need to create a temporary table in one of my stored procedures. The data to be inserted into the temp table is derived from a dynamic pivot query - hence I am tied to dynamic sql. So it becomes something like this -

```
set query = 'select ....'+ pivotcols + 
            ' into ##temp_table
              from base_table
              pivot (
              max(col1)
              for col2 in 
              (' + pivotcols +' as final'

 exec(query)
```

Here I cannot use local temp table (#temp_table), since the table created within the dynamic sql won't be available to the rest of the stored procedure. So I end up using a global temp table (##temp_table).

Now the problem is if there is unforeseen exit from the stored proc where the table does not get dropped properly, it can raise exceptions when someone else tries to use the same sp. Also even without exceptions, if two people run the same procedure, there could be problems. Is there any solution to this problem? Any alternatives I can use?

Note: I have to use dynamic sql - the pivot query cannot be made dynamic in any other way, since the columns that will be pivoted are decided at runtime. But I am flexible to how the data actually goes into the temp table.

EDIT: edited 'variable' in the question heading to 'table'

Comment: On one hand, you're saying you have to use dynamic SQL to build the temp table, because the table structure is determined at runtime (pivoted columns), but on the other hand you're saying the rest of your sproc is not using dynamic sql? Anyway, using dynamic sql for the rest of the proc would be the best.

Comment: It's an unnecessary overhead. I need to just do 'select t.* from ##temp.. ' with a join on some other tables to return the result set to the application. I am looking for some other options if possible before making everything dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could append a value derived from a GUID to the temp table name.  Here's one way that also removes the hyphens.

```
set query = 'select ....'+ pivotcols + 
            ' into ##temp_table' + REPLACE(CAST(NEWID() as varchar(50)), '-','')
```

NEWID() will give a different value each time.

Comment: How do I use the table after that? Remember, I am storing it in the temp table only because I want to use it somewhere down the line in the SP. Do I have to depend on dynamic sql for all the remaining queries as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can check condition that if global temporary table is exists using below sql statements.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('##temp') IS NOT NULL
drop table ##temp
```

Hope it will help for you

Comment: No, this does not work with global temp tables. At least it is not working for me, have you tried it out yourself?

Comment: Yes i have tried and it's working fine at my end. if you find any problem with that please let me know.

Comment: Are you positive you tried with global temp tables? It works fine with normal tables, but not with global temp tables.